# Invalid Json string Google Visualization Chart

Tags: javascript, c#, json, charts, google-visualization

Below is my JSON string

```
{
"cols": [{
    "type": "string",
    "id": "Date",
    "label": "Date"
}, {
    "type": "string",
    "id": "Tweet",
    "label": "Tweet"
}, {
    "type": "number",
    "id": "Retweets",
    "label": "Retweets"
}, {
    "type": "number",
    "id": "Favorites",
    "label": "Favorites"
}],
"rows": [{
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>14 Jan 2016 10:36PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@sammaanchhabra\ We\ would\ like\ to\ assure\ u\ that\ we\ haven''t\ changed\ anything\ related\ to\ weight\.\(1/2\)"
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 1
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>14 Jan 2016 10:35PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@sammaanchhabra\ We\ have\ kept\ these\ entities\ same\ as\ they\ were\ when\ we\ exited\ the\ market\.\ \(2/2\)"
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>14 Jan 2016 11:56AM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@RishutaKarthikD\ You\ can\ surely\ cook\ MAGGI\ Noodles\ in\ 2\ minutes\ by\ following\ the\ suggested\ method\ of\ preparation,\ as\ mentioned\ on\ pack\."
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 07:39PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@BTofficiel\ It''s\ good\ to\ be\ back!\ Enjoy\ your\ MAGGI\ Noodles\ :\)"
    }, {
        "v": 1
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 07:05PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@_clue_less\ we\ missed\ you\ too\ :\)\ Thank\ you\ for\ all\ the\ love\ and\ support\."
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 1
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 01:08PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@AakashRoyDC\ Thanks\ for\ your\ love\ !\ Delighted\ to\ have\ fans\ like\ you\."
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 1
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 11:55AM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@AninBanerjeeeee\ \ In\ the\ initial\ phase\ we\ are\ rolling\ out\ MAGGI\ Noodles\ Masala,\ the\ most\ popular\ variant\ amongst\ our\ consumers\.\ \(1/2\)"
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 11:54AM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@AninBanerjeeeee\ \ \ We\ will\ roll\ out\ some\ of\ our\ other\ variants\ as\ soon\ as\ possible\.\ \(2/2\)"
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>13 Jan 2016 11:18AM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@shrutideb\ \ We\ are\ concerned\ and\ would\ like\ to\ talk\ to\ you\ &amp;\ investigate\.\ Please\ DM\ your\ contact\ and\ location\ details\."
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }]
}, {
    "c": [{
        "v": "<a href='' target='_blank'>12 Jan 2016 11:09PM</a>"
    }, {
        "v": "@Chethan14802058\ We\ are\ in\ touch\ with\ our\ channel\ partners\ and\ distributors\.\ \nThey\ are\ enthusiastic\ about\ the\ re-introduction\ of\ MAGGI\ \(1/2\)"
    }, {
        "v": 0
    }, {
        "v": 1
    }]
}]
}
```

When I pass the JSON in a variable strJSON to

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(strJSON);
```

It gives me error `JavaScript runtime error: Invalid JSON string:`. I have validated the above JSON on jsonlint, but google js is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

First, if you are including this in your JSON code as a string literal using single quotes (that is, you are not loading it via AJAX, but as an actual block of string inside your script), you should make sure that you are escaping all line-breaks (replace them with `\n`) and all single quotes (replace them with `\'`). Line breaks inside a string must be escaped because JS interprets a line break as the end of a statement, which means you will have opened a string literal without ever closing it. And if your string contains the same quotes character that is wrapping it, it will need to be escaped because that would close off the string literal prematurely.

Second, I don't know why you are escaping spaces, periods and braces inside your strings. I can't imagine how that would help or harm you.

Third, it looks like you are escaping your single quotes in the style of SQL. There could be reasons for this, but again, I can't think how it would help you (and if you think it will protect you down the road from SQL injection or something like this, then you probably have deeper problems).

---

[edit]

Based on your comment below, I recommend using the tools Microsoft gives you for [JavaScript serialisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, if you are using any insecure content (for example, user-generated content or anything that originates from outside your control), you should ensure that everything goes through `JSON.parse()`. Otherwise, you leave yourself open to XSS attacks. For example:

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(strJSON),
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(objJSON);
```

Comment: 1) Can you please help me with the replace code for line-breaks in javascript? 2) I am passing this JSON from my C# code on the server side and to avoid any escape characters, I am writing `Regex.Escape("String")` which escapes all those things. 3) This is again because of my C# escape